# Write memory timings for Spartan 7 4:1 Mig Generated DDR3 interface

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan

I'm trying to understand the write memory timings for 7 Series FPGa's using the UI for  a MIG generated memory controller (running at 4:1).

The documentation I'm following is the [ug586](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mig_7series/v4_1/ug586_7Series_MIS.pdf) document from Xilinix. I'm particularly trying to understand Figure 1:77 which is replicated here:

[image: Image 1-77 from ug586_7Series_MIS.pdf]

My understanding is that for the first few cycles, `app_addr` `app_en` `app_wdf_data` `app_wdf_wren` and `app_wdf_end` are correctly asserted and data is written. See the blue lines.

The interesting point comes at (1) where the `app_rdy` is deasserted which means the Memory Controller is busy. At this point the `app_addr` is held on the same address (2) until `app_rdy` is reasserted at (6). All makes sense so far.

What I'm confused by is what is written to address `a30`? The choices are data (3) or (4) or (5). The diagram and logic implies that (3) is written to `a30` (see dotted pink line). But I cant work out why. Looking at figure 1-75 in the docs you can give the write data one clock early but the data at (3) is 2 clocks early when compared to when `app_rdy` is re-enbled at the rising edge of the clock at (7). So that leaves either (4) or (5). But neither of those seem to make sense in this demo. So what is written to `a30` and how do I work this out?

(I'm also interested whats written to the subsequent addresses but once I understand `a30` I should be able to understand those too)

Comment: Looks more like a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ than here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It seems like this is answered [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/7-Series-FPGAs/MIG-back-to-back-write-timing-confusion/td-p/769982)

Comment: It would have been useful if you had included a link to a [UG586 that actually contained the figures referenced in your question](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mig_7series/v4_1/ug586_7Series_MIS.pdf). Your question link contains different Figures not showing the same information (See it's Figures 1-47  thru 1-48). Your figure is from the 2015 - 2018 version of the document, your provided link the [2011 version](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/ug586_7Series_MIS.pdf).

Comment: @user1155120 Apologies you're right - updated the link in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question as I found an almost identical answer [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/7-Series-FPGAs/MIG-back-to-back-write-timing-confusion/td-p/769982).

Basically the confusion is that the command queue (which is controlled by `app_en` and `app_rdy`) is seperate from the write queue (which is controlled by `app_wdf_rdy` and `app_wdf_wren`).

This means that you can queue up the data for writes in advance of actually asking for the write - infact you can keep queueing write data until `app_wdf_ready` is deasserted.

You must queue some write data for each write command. You can queue the write data in advance of the write command, on the same clock as the write command or up to two clocks later. The write data is a FIFO queue so you can queue lots of write data even before issuing a single write command!

(The confusion comes from the example in the docs which show queuing data a single clock early - but if you read the text you get:

> 1. Write data is presented along with the corresponding write command (second half of BL8).
> 2. Write data is presented *before the corresponding write command.*
> 3. Write data is presented after the corresponding write command, but should not exceed the limitation of two clock cycles

Note that in point 2. there is no limitation mentioned of how early you're allowed to queue the data.

This means that - in my exmaple - (3) *is* written to address `a30` as it was in the write queue.